# Prevent class from unload, java

Tags: java, android, variables

In my Android App I have a static class to share some variables and functions within the whole application.

some variables from this class are initiated in other Activities (once, for example, user select something from the grid view, then I store its selection in this static class to use it later in another activity)

Everything was fine, but it looks like that after some period of inactivity of the App (once it stays in the Background), this static class is destroyed and then re-initialized with default values, which are "wrong", let's say.

Or, probably, the whole app is disloaded, and after I call it back, it restores the last activity which is trying to access some variables but they are re-initiaed

It there any way to prevent class from re-initialization or keep the static values or to keep these values somehow else and restore them once activity is re-created?..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for ways (or rather hacks) to stop re-initialisation of your classes or storing the variables in a static class I would rather suggest you to store the state of your app in local storages like Shared Preferences or the SQLite DB.

The advantage of this would be you can access this variables in any part of your app and secondly you will get rid of those static classes and variables which are the main culprit of Memory leaks and ANRs.

Answer (score 0):

I think sharedPreference is the perfect alternative for you. It helps to store your data locally.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answer. It's not a perfect solution for me, because I change this parameter several times during run-time (it's user's choice from another Activity) and I need to get this value from various other activities... So, looking for something else.. static variable would be good solution unless it's not crashes :-/